# Swift Firebase call only display 1 post

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi I am doing a firebase call which is a query to check for the same posts related to a NSDictionary value. The snapshot prints the posts that I want but only 1 post is being displayed. I am trying to think of why it is only displaying 1 post but having a tough time with this.

```
func getAllPosts(refreshing: Bool, refreshControl: UIRefreshControl?) {
    MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.view, animated: true)

    Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(self.otherUser?["uid"] as! String).queryOrdered(byChild: "uid").queryEqual(toValue: self.otherUser?["uid"] as! String).observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
        if snapshot.exists() {
            print(snapshot)

            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                self.feeds = []
                let uid = dictionary["uid"] as? String
                let name = dictionary["businessName"] as? String
                let address = dictionary["businessStreet"] as? String
                let state = dictionary["businessCity"] as? String
                let caption = dictionary["caption"] as? String
                let downloadURL = dictionary["download_url"] as? String
                let timestamp = dictionary["timestamp"] as? Double
                let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timestamp!/1000)
                let postID = dictionary["postID"] as? String

                let lat = Double(dictionary["businessLatitude"] as! String)
                let long = Double(dictionary["businessLongitude"] as! String)

                let businessLocation = CLLocation(latitude: lat!, longitude: long!)

                let latitude = self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude
                let longitude = self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude
                let userLocation = CLLocation(latitude: latitude!, longitude: longitude!)

                let distanceInMeters: Double = userLocation.distance(from: businessLocation)
                let distanceInMiles: Double = distanceInMeters * 0.00062137
                let distanceLabelText = String(format: "%.2f miles away", distanceInMiles)

                let post = Post(uid: uid!, caption: caption!, downloadURL: downloadURL!, name: name!, date: date, address: address!, state: state!, distance: distanceLabelText, postID: postID!)
                self.feeds.append(post)

                // sort posts by date
                self.feeds.sort {$0.date.compare($1.date) == .orderedDescending}
                self.feedTableView.reloadData()
            }

            if refreshing {
                refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
            }
            MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self.view, animated: true)

        } else {
            print("No Snapshot found")
            MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self.view, animated: true)
        }
})
}
```

Comment: You print your snapshot, can you see more than one post when you print that? I recommend posting your data structure and the printed snapshot. It's really hard to help without knowing your data structure.

Comment: You are querying the ref /posts/uid_x/uid where the value of uid is equal to uid_x which is a little odd. Also, .childAdded iterates over the results one at a time which may be what you are intending to do. Can you include your Firebase structure as text please NO Imges (Firebase Console->Export JSON). That may better help us understand that query and what your results are. Also, can you clarify the question a bit? You say it prints the posts (plural) but only 1 post (singular) is being displayed. Does that mean the function is retrieving all the posts but just not displaying them?